# Not getting a response from Mockjax with JsTestDriver

Tags: javascript, jquery, js-test-driver

I'm attempting to use mockjax to mock my jQuery Ajax calls; however, I am not able to find any good, working examples of how to effectively test the responses.

The following code is a simple wrapper for the jQuery.Ajax object.  It works but I want to write some tests around such:

### Ajax Wrapper

```
if (!namespace){ 
    var namespace = {};
}


namespace.Ajax = (function($){

    function defaultError(xhr, err, msg){
        if (typeof console !== 'undefined'){
            var log = console.error;

            if (!log) {
                log = console.log;
            }

            log("==========================================");
            log("An error occurred with the request."); 
            log("- Status Code: " + xhr.status);
            log("- Status Text: " + xhr.statusText);
            log("- Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
            log("- Message: " + msg);
            log("==========================================");
        }
    }

    function getData(url, data, successCallback, errorCallback){
        if (!errorCallback){
            errorCallback = defaultError;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: url
            , data: data
            , success: successCallback
            , error: errorCallback
        });
    }

    function postData(url, data, successCallback, errorCallback){
        if (!errorCallback){
            errorCallback = defaultLog;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST"
            , url: url
            , data: data
            , success: successCallback
            , error: errorCallback
        });
    }

    return {
        getData : getData
        , postData: postData
    }
}(jQuery));
```

I have the following JsTestDriver test for the getData.

### Test Class

```
TestCase("Ajax Object Test Fixture", {
    "test Calling getData Should Return content" : function(){
        var results;
        var obj = namespace.Ajax;

        $.mockjax({
            url: "/test"
            , responseTime: 1
            , responseText: "success"
        });


        obj.getData("/test"
                    , null
                    , function(data){results = data; });

        setTimeout(function(){assertEquals("'success' Should be Returned.", "success1", results);}, 500);
    }
});
```

The **assertEquals function should return false in this example** since I'm expecting "success1" but throughout the code I try to set the value to "success".  I want this test to fail so I know it's working.  As it is though, the test succeeds.  I have event tried to set the successCallback function to just be `results = "success"` and it still doesn't "fail" the test.

How do I set up this test to ensure the mock response is returned so I am not getting the false positive that I have currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that setTimeout causes the testcase to quit without running any assertions, and the assertEquals gets called in a separate "thread".

What you need here is an asynchronous testcase:

```
(function(namespace){
var testcase = AsyncTestCase('AjaxObjectTest');

/**
 * Each asynchronous testcase method receives a queue object.
 */
testcase.prototype.testGetData = function(queue) {
    var results;
    var obj = namespace.Ajax;

    $.mockjax({
        url: "/test",
        responseTime: 1,
        responseText: "success"});

    // Here we pass a function to the queue call method, which will
    // pause the testcase execution until all callback methods have been
    // called, or until it expires.
    queue.call('Expecting a callback', function(callbacks){

        // The callbacks object is a factory for creating required 
        // callback functions. This queued function will wait until it
        // has been called. You can specify the number of times you require
        // it to be called as the second parameter of the add method.
        var handler = callbacks.add(function(data){
            assertEquals("'success' Should be Returned.", "success1", data);
        });

        obj.getData("/test", null, handler);
    }
});
})(namespace);
```

You can have as many queue calls as you want in a single test, and all of them will be run only after the previous one finishes. You can read more about the asynchronous testcase in the JsTestDriver project [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/AsyncTestCase). Hope that helps!

Oh, almost forgot! To avoid cases where you have a passed test with no assertions, you can use the `expectAsserts` function:

```
testcase.prototype.testSomeStuff = function(){
    expectAsserts(2);

    // Test your stuff here
};
```

Comment: Thanks Igor!  I'll give it a try as soon as I get a chance later today.  Regardless, +1 for a lot of great info!

Comment: Finally got around to testing this.  Worked out great.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out! I have recently started using Jasmine, and it seems like they have figured out a way to test asynchronous cases like this with a lot less code. Check it out sometime: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs